# Preview and test email send - URL Expire?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, url, content-builder

I sent a test email on my address email a few month ago, and I wanted to take a look at the test email from that time and also check the URL.
I noticed that the URL expired. Is it normal for a preview and test send?

Thanks!

Comment: As Jonas correctly writes, all tracked links do expire. You can, however, disable click tracking in your particular send, under Additional Options > Track Clicks. This will prevent your links from expire, as they won't redirect via the click tracking domain.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for any send.

Go To

Setup, Feature Settings, Email Studio, URL Expiration

...and you see how long the links in your BU are valid.